# Sql Improve Select Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, max

Hi everyone I have a little problem trying to get data from a table, this is the select im doing:

```
SELECT 
    HOS.Area_Code, 
    HOS.Year,       
    HOS.OrderNumber, 
    MAX(HOS.Id) as 'Id_Order',
    HOS.status,
    MAX(HOS.date_status) as 'date_status',
    HO.Rut, 
    HO.Name, 
    HO.Amount
FROM SDF_Historic_Order_Status as HOS inner join HeaderOrder as HO
ON  
    HOS.Area_Code = HO.Area_Code AND
    HOS.Year = HO.Year AND
    HOS.OrderNumber = HO.OrderNumber
WHERE 
    (HOS.Area_Code= 1) AND
    (HOS.Year= 2017) AND
    (HOS.OrderNumber= 7) AND
    (HOS.date_status < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()))) 
GROUP BY 
    HOS.Area_Code, HOS.Year, HOS.OrderNumber, HOS.status, HO.Rut, HO.Name, HO.Amount
```

It returns 3 rows:
[image: select result]

So what im doing is getting the max ID cause according to that is the current status that the order have. As you can se the Max ID have status 2, is there a way that I can improve my select to get only that row?

I can't put Max Status cause it will return status 5 and the current status is 2.

Comment: RowNumber by the order and partitioning you want. Then filter for those rows only by using the rownumber returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `top` and `order by` if you only want one row:

```
select top (1) . . .
from . . .
. . .
order by id_order desc;
```